# Apns certificate is not installing in my mac book

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate

I got project from client for next release with some changes. Older one having push notifications. Can I use same Apns certificates for next release also? If yes when I tried to installing those certificates no use from my end.Please help me to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates gets installed along with their private keys only in the system from which CSR is generated.

You want to install the certificate on other machine, ask your client to export the certificate from Keychain Access with a password. Then provide that .p12 file to you

Then you will douple tap or drag drop to keychain and it will ask you for the password as provided by your client while exporting the certificate. After installing, you will be able to see the private key in your keychain

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. When I am trying to drag and drop p12 file giving error as Contents of this item can not be retrived. It is very important for me . Need to give update on this in couple of hours

Comment: ask your client to go to keychain and right click on the desired certificate.. choose export certificate. Enter any password and provide it to you

Comment: Ok Thank you so much you saved my time

Comment: If you find my answer useful, Please accept it. Thanks

Comment: if we install p12 file then are pushnotifications work?

Comment: Along with .p12,you also need a provisioning profile for the same + some code in order to make your app register to push notifications and get device token.

Comment: I created dev and prodution profiles and pem files . Uploaded to test server. But still I didnt get any push notifications. Am I miss anything

Comment: in case of production file you don't have to use sandbox. you have to keep production true and use URL as the ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 and not the sandbox one. Also there are separate pem files for each and also device token is not the same for production and development